# Kubernetes: open different service connections between pods

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes

I´ve created two service connections (nodeports) at my pod storage for communicating with the pod app via port 8885 and 8881. I´ve read that I need to use matchselects on the app deployment with the same name, which I gave the nodeport. Can you please show me an working example, where pod app can reach pod storage on port 8881 and 8885?

I´ve tested telnet demo-storage-manageport 8885 and demo-storage-nodeport 8881 within the app container (docker), but it doesn´t work.

Service Connections:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: demo-storage-nodeport
  namespace: demo-customer
  labels:
    run: demo-storage
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 8881
    targetPort: 8881
    protocol: TCP
    name: tomcat-http
  selector:
    app: demo-app
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: demo-storage-manageport
  namespace: demo-customer
  labels:
    run: demo-storage
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 8885
    targetPort: 8885
    protocol: TCP
    name: tomcat-http
  selector:
    app: demo-app
```

Deployments:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: demo-app
  namespace: demo-customer
  labels:
    app: demo-app
    name: appserver
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demo-app
      customer: demo-customer
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: demo-app
        customer: demo-customer
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: appserver
        image: xy.azurecr.io/client/demo-customer-app:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: xy
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: demo-storage
  namespace: demo-customer
  labels:
    app: demo-storage
    name: storageserver
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demo-storage
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: demo-storage
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: shared-config
        emptyDir: {}
      containers:
      - name: storageserver
        image: xy.azurecr.io/client/demo-customer-storage:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8881
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: xy
```

Comment: if you don't specify nodePort: port number you will get a random port, you are trying with the wrong one, kubectl get svc <servicename> -o wide to get the allocated nodeport

Comment: Thanks, so the port / targetport isn´t used for communcating but only the nodeport?

Comment: targetport is the port of the container